# Display SVG file

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, svg

Can someone suggest me a library for svg for java or some code example for displaying svg files? I'm a noob so help please.

Answer (score 13):

You can use [Apache Batik](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/). I downloaded it time ago and it had some examples on displaying SVG. For displaying SVG in a Swing component you can [follow this example](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/using/swing.html).